# One INSERT with UNIONS or multiple INSERTS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a sql function that returns a table. The table is populated via 6 or so reasonably complex statements.

Is it better to UNION together these statement so there is only 1 insert or are these better kept separate?

Or does it make no difference whatsoever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a User Defined Function, I don't see a reason to use one over the other.  A `UNION` has the potential to be more constraining than separate statements...

I'd like to see the details of the function, and it's use, because it's possible it might not be necessary at all.

Comment: it IS possible to do this in a single insert without the unions but it's incredibly messy (trust me, I've had a go)

Answer (score 8):

I will suggest separate inserts. I found that performance of insert with Union All is very poor as compared to separate inserts. I tried inserting around 3500 records using both the approaches, separate insert statements were 4 times faster. (It may vary on number of columns in your insert)

Comment: I concur. Around 1,000,000 rows from around 10 different tables - separate inserts complete in 6 seconds, UNION ALL didn't complete after 10 minutes!

Comment: @MarkRobinson I am having this exact same scenario, UNION ALL takes time in the order of minutes, whereas separate inserts complete in mere less than 10 seconds. Why do you think this is? I have a temp table, populated using a multiple SELECTs with UNION ALL (takes several minutes), then changed it to multiple separate `INSERT INTO #TempTable SELECT ...` statements and it takes only seconds.

Comment: I am guessing when UNION ALL is used, the data is transferred to the application (http requests, hence slow), but with single "Insert INTO ... SELECT...", the db engine is smart enough to realize this can be completed without needing to transmit the data, and thus the whole insert completes right on the DB server? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Breaking large inserts into smaller chunks is generally faster. You will find plenty of articles on the net about chunking inserts. See https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes for example. It is about DELETES but the same principle applies.

Answer (score 7):

I'd just `UNION ALL` them - the key there is not a `UNION` (which could be less efficient by deduping), but a `UNION ALL`.

Comment: I'll try it, because just "UNION" is very slow, unfortunately. 5k rows with 1 column, identical value needs 10 seconds. `UNION ALL` requires less than 1 second. Thank you for that great hint!

Answer (score 6):

Actually, it does make a difference.

When you have separate `INSERT`s, you have to take care to do it inside a transaction, so that you have a consistent state at all times. But, since they're separate, the amount of memory required for the server to complete is less because every `INSERT` has it's own result set - when the query completes the server is free to perform another query etc...

When you have everything inside one big query joined by `UNION ALL` the server would need more temp tables and more memory to complete. But, this way you have something of a 'bulk' insert, and could result in faster insert.

Personally, I'd go with separate inserts inside a transaction. Sometimes just by having something done simpler is way more beneficial in terms of maintainability and debugging than some minor performance gain (if any, depends on the number of rows actually getting inserted)

Comment: you might disagree but in this case I don't believe I need transactions. no data is being updated as a result of these statements, only presented to a user so if a record changes before the whole thing is complete that does not matter to me. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Ok, that's one more reason for separate inserts because transactions don't apply it would be even faster...

Comment: I agree with this.  In my experience, a UNION can unnecessarily slow down an insert process because of the time (and memory) it takes to create the union in the first place.  And often transactions can still be wrapped around separate inserts, even when needed.  I would go with the separate inserts, if we are speaking purely server side database work.

Answer (score 5):

Instead to think by yourself what is the best solution i suggest as a tip to use a properly tool.

In SQL server using the Managment Studio you can evaluate the performance by `Display Estimated Execution Plan`. So in this way you can really see the differences between your 2 cases and select the best one by observing the results.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` v/s `UNION ALL` are not functionally same.
Exercise caution when using `UNION` as it will try to de-dup and potentially that may not be the result you're originally looking for.

Regarding the question, multiple `INSERT`(s) might be faster given the lesser number of records compared to `UNION ALL`